# Need to create a popup form on click of a button in the template header

Tags: hubspot, hubspot-crm, hubspot-cms

I have created a sample header and footer for our revised blog design. I have a requirement for the same. It is to open a popup box on click of a button. It seemed to work from creating a sample page in hubspot. I had created a page added a button and added the popup form using new popup CTA feature. But it failed to work when I tried to open it from the template. I have a header and it has a contact CTA button. I want to open the popup form on clicking the CTA button.

Can anyone please guide how this can be achieved in hubspot.

Thank you